# Error after upgrading to Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

After upgrading to Drupal 7, I'm getting the following error:

> The specified file temporary://fileM5GTNG could not be copied, because
>   the destination directory is not properly configured Drupal 7

I'm sure that the temporary directory is writable by the web server. Also, I notice that javascript files are not being included on my web pages.

Comment: What is wrong with my title and spelling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/sites/all/files` folder and its children also need to be writeable by the web server, check the permissions on those.

If you've got any performance options switched on it's possible you're not getting the JS files because the system tried to generate static versions in the `files` folder and failed.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this tomorrow. I think you are right on though.